# Disabling syntax and maintaining colorscheme [flickering problem]

Tags: gvim, colorscheme, syntax

I have noticed that with

```
set syntax=off
```

option set, the gvim screen doesn't flicker when I scroll the page using `<PageUp>` and `<PageDown>`.

What are the possible solutions, if some exist, to maintain the colorscheme while having the syntax disabled ?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax files define regions of code and links them to highlight groups, which in turn are colored by the colorscheme. So, if you want to keep your colorscheme for more than just ui elements (status/tabline, etc.), you’ll need to `syntax enable`.

That said, there are a few ways to improve the speed of syntax highlighting. See

- [this very detailed QA](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10495/10604)
- [further mention of regexengine and syntime](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2683/10604)
- a QA I won’t link to whose answer is effectively "refactor your code to be smaller and you won’t have this problem"